# Light Sulphur smell

Tags: fermentation, cider, aroma

Started my first batch of Cider! YEY!
Got me some nice juice from the orchard nearby. It was only pasteurized when i got it, no campden tablets or sulphites to kill the wild yeast.
Started fermantation on 20.9, after 4 days i noticed some light sulphur smel, got me educated a bit and droped some raisins to feed the hungry yeasts. Temperature droped 2 deg Celsius, weather is changing to more cold one.

Q;
Have this lightly sulfur smell, got me pack of nutrients will pitch it tomorrow, how long does it take for the sulfur smell to go away? Or how does it work now in this stage of fermentation? 
I know that idealy i should drop some nutrients w the yeast but didnt get it on-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sulphur is (unfortunately) a side product in some fermentations. Lagers also tend to throw a LOT of sulphur during fermentation! The good news is: If you can smell it, it means it is no longer in your cider! :)

Unless you are making a very strong cider, I do not think that adding nutrients now will make a difference. Your fermentation should be nearly complete after 4 days in any way. [**EDIT**: Cider does not ferment the same speed as beer, so my comment regarding the 4 days is incorrect!]

You do not need to feed the yeast with raisins. They should eat the sugars that are in the must. If they have done with the sugars they will fall to the bottom and your cider will be ready for consumption.

Note: Pasturization should kill wild yeast.

Comment: Thanks for nice clarification. Another question, as in the said batch is pretty cloudy, got it like that already, will pectin enzym produce more sugar for yest to ferment more? I read on hbtalk that it breaks some cell bariers thus releasing more sugars in the batch. Are there any cons for adding pectin in this stage?

Comment: If there are any unfermentable sugars left in the beer then the enzyme will break those sugars up into fermentable sugars, yes. But remember that you still want some sugars to remain in the drink, otherwise it will almost be like drinking a vodka and water mix. I would not recommend adding pectin. Let it ferment out, see what it tastes like, and then decide if you want to make it even drier.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Basicly its still bubling a bit and releasing some bubles and the smell, ill wait for it to settle and drink a glass tonite!

Comment: I would not drink it that "fresh". There will still be a lot of yeast in suspension. When the bubbling has stopped and the FG is stable for three days, then I would cool the cider to allow the yeast to properly drop out. This will give you a clearer product. At that point you can then bottle/keg and carbonate (if you want to).

Comment: I see, totaly forgot this one fg readings and crash cool, yes i would like it to be fizzy, but ill leave that for the next batch. Im trying to educate myself! Thanks for all the answers Atron!

Comment: I highly recommend How To Brew by John Palmer. I know it is for beer, but there is a LOT of info that applies to all fermentation hobbies. Bottling & fizzy is easy, except for the amount of cleaning! I hope it tastes good.

Comment: thanks for the clues, this is what i need. we are most wine producing country here, but on all my trips across France i drank a lot of good cider stuff. will get me the book and illuminate my skills :)

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that making cider is a lot more like making wine than making beer.  I ferment my ciders for several months.  That allows time for them to clear and for off aromas to ferment out.

Comment: understand, im getting more and more info, seems 2 oposites  sides - or its a turbo cider 2-weeks time or is months in a barrel.

Comment: Decide for yourself, but I've never tasted a good fast cider.

Comment: Thanks Denny, i will surely let it sit for some time. Plan is to leave it in some oak barrel to sit out and get some flavours back (as i read on some topics). Next batch ill do it differently since i learned a lot from this one (and still learning). Cant wait to taste it ;)

Comment: Oh... now I learnt something BIG! I did not know that ciders ferment so slowly. I assumed that they run the same speed as beer. I will update my answer...

Comment: It's not that they take a long time to ferment...it's more that they take a long time to age and mature, like wine.

Comment: I can confirm that is not giving any smell, ive racked it to remove it from the yeast cake. All went smooth. Now its sitting and bubled a bit after the syphoning. All in all, great fun. Will leave it to sit sometime...